# Looking for an alternative to alt+tab in Compiz

Tags: ubuntu, compiz

I would like to define a keyboard shortcut in Compiz that allows me to:

- move the focus to the next window
- do not keep a history of visited windows, just cycle through all windows on a workspace
- do not display *any* popups or fancy effects

How can this be achieved?

*Update:* to be clear, I am looking for an alternative to the default alt+tab functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hah. No popups at all.

- Open compiz configuration (in Ubuntu: System → Preferences → CompizConfig Settings Manager or `ccsm` or whatever).
- Enable only the Application Switcher plugin from all the switchers available.
- In the Bindings tab, disable the “Next Window” and “Prev Window” bindings and set “Next Window (No popup)” to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and “Prev Window (No popup)” to <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd get better answers to this question if you said what you didn't like about the default Alt-Tab functionality in Compiz. There are four switchers that come with a full install of Compiz: "Application Switcher", "Static Application Switcher", "Ring Switcher" and "Shift Switcher". Like with just about anything in Compiz, you can map the keyboard shortcuts (Alt-Tab or something else, e.g., Super-tab) to use any of these.

You said you didn't want anything fancy, so Ring Switcher and Shift Switcher are probably out (they're fairly fancy). But "Application Switcher" and "Static Application Switcher" are both fairly un-fancy, and you can customize them. If Alt-Tab is currently set to work with "Application Switcher", then change it to "Static Application Switcher" or vice-versa. Each has options you can play around with. (E.g., you can change the speed, or turn on and off the mipmap, highlight the active one or make the others transparent, etc.)

Of course these are all set through `ccsm` (CompizConfig Settings Manager).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the active Switcher caused Unity hang-ups everytime.

I opened another tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>), logged on and typed `unity --reset`.
This triggers something like a restart of the unity graphical userinterface.
Go back to unity-tty7 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and find unity working again.

It does not overwrite last changes to App-Switchers within CCSM.

Next version something like automatic reset should be implemented I guess.